# LINQ to SQL Query

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have got a query which returns True or False, depending on the criteria set in the query:

```
 bool eventVoucherUsed = getAllBookings.Any(r => r.EventID == booking.EventID && r.Voucher != null) ? true : false;
```

I want to modify the above query by adding one more check:

```
 booking.VoucherStatus == True
```

But I can't use the `And` operator three times. Is there any other alternative to achieve this?

Comment: Why can't you use && 3 times? Also, your ? true : false is pointless, any already returns true or false

Comment: Why can't you use the && operator three times?  You might be able to do ".Where().Where().Where().Any()", but the two &&'s would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "cant use And operator three times". All that you need to do is add the condition to your predicate.

```
bool eventVoucherUsed = 
     getAllBookings.Any(r => r.EventID == booking.EventID 
                   && r.Voucher != null 
                   && booking.VoucherStatus == true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if your example is accurate booking is something you already know so I can't see any reason too not just check that before even hitting the database:

```
bool eventVoucherUsed = 
  booking.VoucherStatus 
  ? getAllBookings.Any(r => r.EventID == booking.EventID && r.Voucher != null)
  : false;
```